# Use hclust function with a custom distance for linkage methods

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hclust

I want to do an agglomerative clustering with R, but I want to use my own distance as a linkage method instead of the ones already predefined. How can I can I embed my own distance as a linkage method using the function hclust in R?

Comment: The function is defined as `hclust(d, method = "complete", members = NULL)`, where `d` is a dissimilarity matrix as produced by function `dist`. Your custom dissimilarity function should return an object compatible with `dist`'s return value. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Suppose that I use the correlation dissimilarity. Will the function hclust use this distance in the linkage method as well?

Comment: Yes, it will. `hclust` will operate on the dissimilarity matrix it is given.